# When calling Delegate Lib API got error InValidFunctionPointerInDelegate was detected

Tags: .net, vb.net, delegates

```
Dim fl_prevproc As SubClassProcDelegate
```

I have created function as below:

```
Public Function SetupClassNotification() As Boolean
   Dim subclassform As System.Windows.Forms.Form
   Dim i As Integer
      For i = 0 To FORMLIST_END 
        If Formlist(i).fl_threadid = 0 Then 
        subclassform = New frmSubclassingForm 
        subclassform.Hide() 
        Formlist(i).fl_prevproc = SetWindowLong(subclassform.Handle.ToInt32, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf WindowProc)
        Exit Function
        End If
      Next i
End Function
```

Implementation of WindowProc Function with exactly same argument as Delegate Function

```
Private Function WindowProc(ByVal hw As Integer, ByVal uMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

    Dim i As Integer

    If uMsg = VB_WM_USER_PLUS_1 Then 

        CheckForResponses() 
    Else 
        For i = 0 To FORMLIST_END 
            If hw = Formlist(i).fl_gHW Then 
                WindowProc = CallWindowProc(Formlist(i).fl_prevproc, hw, uMsg, wParam, lParam) 
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```

Declaration for Lib API is as follows:

```
Delegate Function SubClassProcDelegate(ByVal hw As Integer, ByVal uMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32.dll" Alias "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As SubClassProcDelegate, ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal attr As Integer, ByVal lVal As SubClassProcDelegate) As SubClassProcDelegate
```

Execution stops at a line:

```
Formlist(i).fl_prevproc = SetWindowLong(subclassform.Handle.ToInt32, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf WindowProc)
```

The error message I'm getting is

> Invalid function pointer 0xffff0a95 was passed into the runtime to be
>   converted to a delegate. Passing in invalid function pointers to be
>   converted to delegates can cause crashes, corruption or data loss.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring the window handle as `Integer` is asking for problems especially if you are using a 64 bit OS; use `IntPtr` or [SafeHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle(v=vs.110).aspx).  `wParam`, and `lParam` should also be IntPtr.

That said, why not use the .Net [NativeWindow Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples) to hook into the window procedure?

Edit:

Here is a working example using the Win32 API.  I still recommend that you implement a solution based on the NativeWindow class.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
    Private prevWndProc As IntPtr
    Public Delegate Function WndProcDelegate(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As UInt32, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLong")> _
    Private Shared Function SetWindowLong32(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As Int32, ByVal dwNewLong As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLongPtr")> _
    Private Shared Function SetWindowLongPtr64(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As Int32, ByVal dwNewLong As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Private Shared Function SetWindowProc(hwnd As IntPtr, wndProcDelegate As WndProcDelegate) As IntPtr
        Const GWL_WNDPROC As Int32 = -4

        Dim ptr As IntPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(wndProcDelegate)
        If IntPtr.Size = 8 Then
            Return SetWindowLongPtr64(hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, ptr)
        Else
            Return SetWindowLong32(hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, ptr)
        End If
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function CallWindowProc(lpPrevWndFunc As IntPtr, hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As UInt32, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        prevWndProc = SetWindowProc(Me.Handle, AddressOf MyWindowProcedure)
    End Sub

    Private Function MyWindowProcedure(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As UInt32, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        Debug.Print(msg.ToString)
        Return CallWindowProc(prevWndProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Tried with IntPtr as well. Didn't worked. That code is in Module. Can I still use  the .Net NativeWindow Class?

Comment: @H.P., I have added an example using the API functions.  I still suggest that you try to implement a NativeWindow based solution as is shown in the example for that class.